# Mzgento 2 : Hide state/province from new address form in backoffice

Tags: magento2, php, backend, address

I need some help for what I'm trying to do: remove or disable the state/province field in new/edit address form in backoffice unless the admin choose some specific countries.

Is there anyway fo remove/disable it from xml or php code ? please help me on this.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In stores->Configuration->General set the value to No for allow to choose state if it is optional for country

[image]